# Linq2Db - The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

Tags: string, initialization, connection, linq2db

I have a solution containing separate project (Linq2Db) than the Mvc Asp.Net Core project. In my startup.cs I have followed instructions found on linq2db github explaining how to set connection string, but once I execute a linq query I am receiving error 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized'.
   If I do not use separate project for linq2db, and I place everything in Mvc project, then all works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem happened because the Linq2db project was referenced by Application project which was then referenced by MVC project. Once I tried using Linq2Db project from MVC without intermediate project in the middle the problem stopped happening.